# How is the Travis CI Github integration actually working?

Tags: github, travis-ci, badge

I am really only interested in how Github can display the Badge status of the passing / failed build. I has to access Travis somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a repo/branch-specific image URL, where Travis changes the image source stored at that URL to a "passing" or "failing" image depending on the result of the build.

Comment: While a simple question, I had to get behind the concept. Will propose the concept to be used to implement some quality metrics for Open Data.